# Twitter reply bot replies to its own replies (infinite feedback loop)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

New to the tweepy api.

I'm using the github script here: https://github.com/twitterdev/sample-python-autoreply

```
        if retweeted is not None and not retweeted and not from_self:

            tweetId = tweet.get('id_str')
            screenName = tweet.get('user',{}).get('screen_name')
            tweetText = tweet.get('text')

            chatResponse = chatbot.respond(tweetText)

            replyText = '@' + screenName + ' ' + chatResponse

            #check if repsonse is over 140 char
            if len(replyText) > 140:
                replyText = replyText[0:139] + '…'

            print('Tweet ID: ' + tweetId)
            print('From: ' + screenName)
            print('Tweet Text: ' + tweetText)
            print('Reply Text: ' + replyText)

            # If rate limited, the status posts should be queued up and sent on an interval
            twitterApi.update_status(status=replyText, in_reply_to_status_id=tweetId)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
```

I managed to get it working but it seems to reply to itself infinitely. Is there a way to limit this? Or to fix it so it doesn't reply to itself? I'm assuming it's only checking for @botusername and replying to those tweets. The rest of the code is available in that github link (it's autoreply.py).

Comment: Seems like the `from_self` check should stop self-replies. Have you verified that `from_self` is definitely True when the tweet is coming from your bot? Maybe the structure of the data is something different from what you expect, and you're getting False when you shouldn't.

Comment: I would also add the few lines before the code you pasted (especially in light of @Kevin's remark), making it closer to a [MCVE]. Also: the username seems to come from the [config file](https://github.com/twitterdev/sample-python-autoreply/blob/master/.twitter.sample). Natural question: did you set the right credentials there?

Comment: I just realized what was broken, I don't understand how it works but it works. Basically instead of using the .twitter config file that the github project uses I instead used a keys.py containing the same exact information. Everything else was identical, (with the exception that I reformatted `consumer_key = config.get('apikey', 'key')` to `CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']` and I'm assuming that's where it broke. I'm gonna edit my question and fix it